# PHP session variable clearing unexpectedly, db value check empty despite obvious match

Tags: php, variables, pdo, session-variables, return-value

I have been struggling with this one for hours and hours and just cannot figure out what I'm missing.

I'm trying to build a cookie-less login form that also has no information in session variables that would harm the app if an attacker would be able to modify them.

All of my pages have the below code included.

I have 2 issues:

1. Every time I click on another page it acts like $_SESSION['token'] was empty and goes to the login page like if it was the first visit.
2. It returns $tokenid and $tokentype empty however I'm calling them both every time a page is loading (aiming to avoid having to put them into a session variable).

This is my current code:

```
<?php

define('TIMEOUTMIN', 15);

define('LOCKOUTMIN', 10);

define('LOCKOUTNUM', 3);

include("includes/pp/pbkdf2.php"); // this is basically calling the validate_password function

include ("includes/vars/vars_dbconn.php"); // this contains the db data and $pdo

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$userpw = $_POST['password'];

$deltoq = "UPDATE LoginUser SET token = ?, online = ? WHERE online < ?";
$prepdeltoq = $pdo->prepare($deltoq);
$prepdeltoq->execute(array(NULL,NULL,time()));

$loginq = "SELECT * FROM LoginUser WHERE ID = ?";
$preplq = $pdo->prepare($loginq);
$preplq->execute(array($userid));
$getuser = $preplq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dbid = $getuser['ID'];
$dbpass = $getuser['hash'];
$dbbp = $getuser['bp'];
$dbltime = $getuser['ltimeout'];

$logintoq = "SELECT * FROM LoginUser WHERE token = ?";
$prepltq = $pdo->prepare($logintoq);        
$prepltq->execute(array($_SESSION['token']));
$getoken = $prepltq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tokenid = $getoken['ID'];
$tokentype = $getoken['type'];
$totoken = $getoken['token'];

$prolonglock = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET ltimeout = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$addbp = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET bp = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$loginwhen = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET lastlogin = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$loginlogq = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO LoginUserLog (ID, action)       
    VALUES(:ID, :action)");

$logintokenid = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET token = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$loginonid = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET online = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$loginontok = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LoginUser SET online = ? WHERE token = ?");

if(!function_exists('LoginUser')) {

    function LoginUser($pwmessage) {

        if (session_name() <> 'MyWebApp') session_name('WesoftskyLogin');
        if (!session_id()) session_start();

        $_SESSION['token'] = '';

        include ("includes/header.php"); ?>
        <meta name="description" content="Login - MyWebApp"/>
        <title>Login - MyWebApp</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            event.keyCode == '';
                function enterTab() {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    var passInput = document.getElementById("password");
                    passInput.focus();
                    }
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onkeyup="enterTab()">
      <div id="homewrap">
        <div id="hometitle">MyWebApp</div>
      </div>
      <div id="id_formwrap">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" method="post">
            <?php if (empty($pwmessage)) echo '<div>Please enter your login details</div>'; else echo '<div style="color:red">'.$pwmessage.'</div>'; ?><br />
            Login ID<br />
            <input type="text" name="userid" id="id" onKeyPress="return noenter(event)" /><br /><br />            
            <script>document.getElementById("id").focus()</script>
            Password<br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="Submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php exit();
    }
}

if(!function_exists('ProlongTime')) {
    function ProlongTime() {
        global $userid; 
        global $logintokenid;
        global $loginonid;
        global $loginontok;
        $timeoutodb = (time () + TIMEOUTMIN*60);
        if (!empty($userid)) {
            $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
            $logintokenid->execute(array($_SESSION['token'], $userid));
            $loginonid->execute(array($timeoutodb, $userid));
        } else {
            $loginontok->execute(array($timeoutodb, $_SESSION['token']));
        }
    }
}

if ($dbltime > time()) {
    $lockcheck = time() + LOCKOUTMIN*60;
    $prolonglock->execute(array($lockcheck,$userid));
    LoginUser('Your account is currently locked');
}

if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    $action = "Logged OUT";
    $loginlogq->execute(array(':ID' => $tokenid, ':action' => $action));
    LoginUser('Logged out');
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {   
    if ($dbid AND validate_password($userpw, $dbpass)) {  // Good login info
        //session_regenerate_id(true);      
        $action = "Logged IN";
        $loginlogq->execute(array(':ID' => $userid, ':action' => $action));
        $loginwhen->execute(array(time(), $userid));
        $addbp->execute(array(NULL, $userid));
        ProlongTime();
    } else { // Bad login info
        if ($dbbp >= LOCKOUTNUM-1) {
            $lockbp = time() + LOCKOUTMIN*60;
            $prolonglock->execute(array($lockbp,$userid));
            $action = "Locked (wrong password)";
            $loginlogq->execute(array(':ID' => $userid, ':action' => $action));
            LoginUser('Your account has been locked');
        }
        $addbp->execute(array($dbbp+1, $userid));
        $action = "Failed login";
        $loginlogq->execute(array(':ID' => $userid, ':action' => $action));
        LoginUser('Username or password is incorrect');
    }
} elseif (empty($_SESSION['token'])) { // Loading the page first time (new session)
    LoginUser('');
} elseif ($_SESSION['token'] <> $totoken) { // Session timeout
    $action = "Logged OUT (expired)";
    $loginlogq->execute(array(':ID' => $tokenid, ':action' => $action));
    echo 'tokenid: '.$tokenid;
} else ProlongTime(); // While using the app and still within time


$pdo = null;

?>
```

Comment: as already answered, the session only gets started in `LoginUser`. After that (e.g. a successful login), no session is started ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put

```
session_start()
```

in the starting of the page.